# Time zone mismatch calling date via ssh

Tags: linux, date, ssh, centos

I'm getting two different timezones on Linux (CENTOS 5.6) depending on whether date is called locally or via ssh:

```
foo$ ssh me@bar date
Tue Nov  5 18:08:32 EST 2013

foo$ ssh me@bar

bar$ date
Tue Nov  5 17:09:16 CST 2013
```

`/etc/localtime` is set to central time:

```
$ ls -l /etc/localtime 
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 27 Nov  5 13:10 /etc/localtime -> /usr/share/zoneinfo/CST6CDT
```

TZ is set to `America/Chicago` in .bash_profile. If that line is commented out, time zone comes back as eastern rather than central.

I'm assuming this all means the computer believes in its heart that it's on eastern rather than central time and the TZ setting in the shell just overrides this, but I can't figure out WHY the computer thinks it's in eastern time.

**edit**
It turned out that a runaway process somewhere had actually overwritten the central time timezone file with an eastern time timezone file. Not easy to find, as the file contents are binary!

Comment: https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=linux+set+timezone

Answer (score 0):

Did you check -> /etc/sysconfig/clock ?

Comment: On Centos what if my clock is,/////// Sat 08 Feb 2014 06:29:55 AM AFT  -0.976379 seconds////////////now if i want to change it to time zone of asia/kabul .... can you tell me how to do that... have tried many ways even after restart system, no result same as before

Comment: cp /usr/share/zoneinfo/Asia/Kabul /etc/localtime